# heron Topologies keep running after deactivating

Tags: apache-storm, scheduling, resource-management, stream-processing, heron

I'm currently working on Heron & Apache Storm for some resource management and scheduling Research.

I noticed that after submitting topologies to Heron, they start running and taking resources, but after deactivating them, it appears that they are still running in the background and take 100% of CPU and RAM! Am i missing something? The way i understand it and based on [heron docs](http://twitter.github.io/heron/docs/concepts/topologies/), deactivating topologies should halt them and stops them from processing new tuples,

> deactivate the topology. Once deactivated, the topology will stop processing but remain running in the cluster.

But when i check the heron-ui after deactivation, it's still processing new tuples, because emit count keeps changing! but when i kill them, everything goes back to normal! Is it normal? And if not, what's the problem?

Comment: Just suggestion: you might need to tag 'heron' instead of 'apache-storm' since twos are not same. Apache Storm users can't answer Heron specific issue.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and i considered adding heron tag but unfortunately there are no tags available for heron!

Comment: Are these custom spouts? if you do not properly implement the deactivate method things will continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the version of Heron to clarify the problem. I have ran the Heron with 0.17.1 and 0.17.5, there is no problem about this.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating a topology stops spouts/sources from pulling any new data, but the bolts will continue to process until all pending data has been drained.